# NPE is thrown when sending concurrent requests to persist entities and relationships in Spring Data Neo4j 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am persisting a Node entity that contains relationships to few other entities. This persist works fine when I am doing it one at a time, however if I run this concurrently, I get NPE at
     org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.updateRelationship(EntityGraphMapper.java:618) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapRelationshipEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:481) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.link(EntityGraphMapper.java:330) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntityReferences(EntityGraphMapper.java:265) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:158) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
```

Here is my Node entity's crux:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Post {
   @Relationship(type = "POST_BY_USER", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
   User poster;

   @Relationship(type = "POST_TO_STORE", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
   Store toStore;

   @Relationship(type = "POST_PRODUCT", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
  Product product;

  @Relationship(type = "POST_INSPIRATION", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
  Product_Inspiration productInspiration;
}
```

I tried persisting with both using a GraphRepository with (@Transactional)as well as using a session with the transaction, in both scenarios, i hit the same issue with concurrency.

Could someone please let me know how I could possibly fix this issue? Since I am getting this issue when I bombard concurrent requests, I am not sure if this could be something with the code flow as such.

As requested by Vince about code how to send concurrent requests, I am using axon cqrs framework with Play and I send multiple concurrent requests to my Play application's rest API which via axon invokes concurrent writes to Neo4j via postProduct method.
here is how my write code looks like.

```
   def postProduct(productId: ProductId, product2Post: Product2Post):     Post = workNLogOnFail(
  doPost(productId, product2Post),
  "postProduct"
  )

  private def doPost(productId: ProductId, product2Post: Product2Post): Post = {
  val product: Product = configureDomainEntity(productId, product2Post)
  val storeId: StoreId = storeService1.findOrCreateStore(product2Post.host)
  val post: Post = commonService.configurePost(product2Post.commonData2Post.relationInfo, isProduct = true) { (x: Post) =>
  x.setToStore(storeService1.updateStoreForProductPost(x, storeId))
  x.setProduct(product)
}
val persistedPost = xtPostProduct(product, post)
commonService.addUrlMapping(product2Post.commonData2Post, productId.identifier)
persistedPost
}
private def xtPostProduct(product: Product, post: Post): Post = {
Try {
  val tx: Transaction = session.beginTransaction()
  logger.debug(s"saving product")
  //      session.save(product)
  logger.debug(s"updating user")
  //      session.save(post.getPoster)
  logger.debug(s"posting product")
  session.save(post)
  tx.commit()
  post
  }.get
  }
```

i tried @Transanctional with GraphRepository as well as session in the method xtPostProduct.

Comment: Please could you post some code here showing how you're doing the concurrent writes?

Comment: Thanks for the code Gaurav.

I am not at all familiar with axon, but the test harness for the OGM contains a number of concurrency tests. That's not to say we don't have concurrency bugs - but we haven't found them yet.

Please could you confirm that the method `doPost` is not sharing state somehow between threads and tripping over itself. In particular are the methods on `StoreService` and `CommonService` as well as `configureDomainEntity`  thread safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The issue was that due to spring DI wiring, my session or also the one used by repositories was not per unit of work. Since i am invoking Database operations via Axon, having the normal way of using a Session Bean with the scope of "session" will not work. I have reverted to manually creating session for each Axon-event that I need to handle. Since essentially for me, that is my unit of work !!.